# Creating a non-linear scale for JSlider

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a non-linear scale for a `JSlider`, however, what I am currently using has large gaps in the scale which makes it less than desirable.

This is because of the way I have set the divisions. For example, when the slider is on `300` the accuracy is `1661` but when the slider is on `301` the accuracy is `9192`.

Is there a way to make the gaps smaller without adding in a lot of extra ranges. For example without doing lots of

```
else if(temp > 150 && temp <= 250)
    accuracy = (int) Math.pow((double) accSlide.getValue(), 1.2);
```

*Edit*
The purpose of this `JSlider` is to have 3 to 4 different sections of acceleration between numbers. For example

```
Section 1 (First quarter of JSlider) : 0-150
Section 2 (Second quarter of JSlider): 150-10000
Section 3 (Third quarter of JSlider) : 10000-100000
Section 4 (Final quarter of JSlider) : 100000-1000000
```

This `accuracy` variable will then be used later on in a different function in the program. In the following short code example, it is shown as an updating `JLabel`. What is the best way to achieve this using a `JSlider`?

---

**SSCCE/MCVE**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Slider extends JFrame {
private int accuracy = 150;
    private Slider() {
        super("Slider");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createLayout();
        setSize(400, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createLayout() {
        JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel acc = new JLabel("Accuracy: " + accuracy);
        JSlider accSlide = new JSlider(1, 1000, accuracy);

        accSlide.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                int temp = accSlide.getValue();
                if(temp <= 150)
                    accuracy = accSlide.getValue();
                else if(temp > 150 && temp <= 300)
                    accuracy = (int) Math.pow((double) accSlide.getValue(), 1.3);
                else if(temp > 300 && temp <= 600)
                    accuracy = (int) Math.pow((double) accSlide.getValue(), 1.6);
                else if(temp > 600 && temp <= 1000)
                    accuracy = (int) Math.pow((double) accSlide.getValue(), 2);
                acc.setText("Accuracy: " + accuracy);
            }
        });
        rootPanel.add(acc);
        rootPanel.add(accSlide, "grow");

        add(rootPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Slider());
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it all hinge on your equation that you use to calculate (the terribly non-Java standard named) variable SQRT_DIG from the slider's value? Your current equation results in terrible discontinuities, which you're seeing, and instead you will need to tweak the equation to be much smoother. Since we don't know your equation needs, this seems to be a problem the only you can solve.

Comment: Your function has gigantic jumps. https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/continuity.html

Comment: You should probably add appropriate offsets to the equation cases such that it generates equal values at 300 & 301

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear what I wanted achieving

Comment: You need to look up curve fitting algorithms and then write in Java the best curve that fits your data transformation closest.

Comment: Thank you for both of your helps

Comment: For example a simple geometric progression would work with data going from 1 to 1000000 if desired. It wouldn't hit the exact data points that you've mentioned, but it would be an easy curve to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

There are some simple ways of doing this but the important thing is to start at the max of the previous range; e.g.

```
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            int temp = accSlide.getValue();
            double max=0;
            if(temp <= 150)
                accuracy = accSlide.getValue();
            else if(temp <= 300)
                accuracy = (int) (150+2*(accSlide.getValue()-150));
           else if(temp <= 600)
                accuracy = (int) (150+2*(300-150)+3*(accSlide.getValue()-300));
            else
                accuracy = (int) ( (150+2*(300-150)+3*(600-300))+4*(accSlide.getValue()-600));
           acc.setText("i " + temp+" Accuracy: " + accuracy);
        }
    });
```

or

```
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            int temp = accSlide.getValue();
            double max=0;
            if(temp <= 150)
                accuracy = accSlide.getValue();
            else if(temp <= 300) {
                max=150;
                accuracy = (int) (max+2*(accSlide.getValue()-150));
           }
           else if(temp <= 600) {
                max=150+2*(300-150);
                accuracy = (int) (max+3*(accSlide.getValue()-300));
           }
            else {
                max=150+2*(300-150)+3*(600-300);
                accuracy = (int) ( (max+4*(accSlide.getValue()-600));
           acc.setText("i " + temp+" Accuracy: " + accuracy);
        }
    });
```

for a series of lines with higher slopes.

Or for your example:

```
            if(temp <= 150)
                accuracy = accSlide.getValue();
              else if(temp <= 300)
                accuracy = (int) (150+Math.pow(accSlide.getValue()-150, 1.3));
           else if(temp <= 600)
                accuracy = (int) (150+Math.pow(300-150, 1.3)+Math.pow((double) accSlide.getValue()-300, 1.6));
            else
                accuracy = (int) ( (150+Math.pow(300-150, 1.3)+Math.pow(600-300, 1.6))+Math.pow((double) accSlide.getValue()-600, 2));
            acc.setText("i " + temp+" Accuracy: " + accuracy);
```